# Avoiding undefined behaviour: temporary objects

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, lifetime, object-lifetime, temporary-objects

I've written a class for using it as a convenient view e.g. in range-based `for`s. Overall, it is just a pair of iterators with bound checking:

```
template<typename I> class Range {
private:
  I begin;
  I end;

public:
  Range(I const begin, I const end)
    : begin(begin), end(end)
  {}

  Range<I>& skip(int const amount) {
    begin = std::min(begin + amount, end);
    return *this;
  }
};

template<typename C> auto whole(C const& container) {
  using Iterator = decltype(std::begin(container));
  return Range<Iterator>(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
}
```

Here's the intended usage of it (which led to UB):

```
std::vector<int> const vector{1, 2, 3};
for (int const value : whole(vector).skip(1)) {
  std::cout << value << ' ';
}
```

Removing the `skip(1)` part helps, same about the following refactoring of `Range::skip`:

```
Range<I> skip(int const amount) const {
  I const new_begin = std::min(begin + amount, end);
  return Range<I>(new_begin, end);
}
```

It seems like a temporary mustn't return a reference to itself. Here's what cppreference says:

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation.

Though I'm not sure it's the case and I don't now how to interpret it practically. What's the actual problem and how can I reliably avoid such UB? Are alike expressions e.g. `auto string = std::string("abc").append("def")` also unsafe?

Comment: the way I solved it is to have a conditional inheritance of something that contains the container iterated over and then move to it. So if you construct with a const& you use a reference, if you construct with && you store it. I did this long time ago, but now it should be fairly trivial to do with std::conditional_t, if constexpr, and auto return type

Comment: something like this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd13537bbb044312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [ranged-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) the *range-expression* is bound to reference as (prototype code)

```
auto && __range = whole(vector).skip(1) ;
```

The problem is the temporary created by `whole(vector)` is destroyed immediately after the full expression, the reference `__range` (which binds to the returned reference from `skip`, i.e. the temporary) becomes dangled; after that any dereference on it leads to UB.

`auto string = std::string("abc").append("def")` is fine, `string` gets copied, it's an independent object from the temporary `std::string`.

Since C++20 you can add [*init-statement*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Temporary_range_expression):

> If *range_expression* returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended until the end of the loop, as indicated by binding to the forwarding reference **__range**, but beware that the lifetime of any temporary within *range_expression is not* extended.

E.g.

```
std::vector<int> const vector{1, 2, 3};
for (auto thing = whole(vector); int const value : thing.skip(1)) {
  std::cout << value << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A range-for holds a reference to the range. Your example

```
for (int const value : whole(vector).skip(1)) {
  std::cout << value << ' ';
}
```

is defined to be equivalent to

```
{
    auto && __range = whole(vector).skip(1);
    auto __begin = __range.begin();
    auto __end = __range.end();
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        int const value = *__begin;
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
}
```

The reference returned by `skip` becomes invalid at the first `;`.

Where you are initialising an object, like

```
std::string s = std::string("abc").append("def");
```

it is safe, because the temporary only needs to outlive the constructor.

As an aside, I prefer `Range<I> skip(int) const` over the mutating one.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `std::string` and [the `append` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append), the `append` function returns a *reference* to the string it appends to. Keeping this reference after the string object is destructed will lead to undefined behavior if you use it.

*However* if you copy the string object, then you're safe, because you will have a *copy* of the string and not a reference to a non-existing object:

```
std::string s = std::string("abc").append("def");
```

Here `s` will be a *copy*, initialized through copy-initialization (it passes `std::string("abc").append("def")` to the copy-constructor for `s`, and the temporary object will live all throughout that constructor).

---

As for

```
for (int const value : whole(vector).skip(1)) { ... }
```

If the `Range<T>` class was modified to be iterable (you need a `begin` and `end` *functions* to return the iterators), then it still would not be UB.

That's because such a range-for loop is corresponding to a loop like

```
for (auto iter = whole(vector).skip(1).begin();
     iter != whole(vector).skip(1).end();
     ++iter)
{
    ...
}
```

The `Range<T>` class doesn't contain a copy of the vector, it contains copies of the *iterator* of the vector (for your shown example). These iterators would be copied or used *before* the temporary `Range<T>` object is destructed.

Comment: Your "loop like" would also forbid `whole(vector)` which is fine.

Comment: Oof sorry, I didn't write begin() and end() in the example.